# Auto set Woocommerce product ID as SKU on save

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use the product ID as SKU on my shops. Is there a way to auto add the product ID as SKU when a new product is created.

Currently I am using a plugin for that but it adds a new row in WP_options table. I have more than 1000 rows now (with Autoload). I guess it might be having some performance impact so want to deactivate it and use code.

Comment: The plugin adds _one_ new row to `wp_options`? Or one per product? Adding one row to `wp_options` is not going to have a measurable impact on performance.

Comment: 1 Row per product! That is why I have more than 1000 rows from this plugin in WP_Options till now.

Comment: I don't know why you need rows in wp_options. Shouldn't this be post meta?